# Show/Hide div with checkboxes using classes multiple times on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble getting my script to work here. I am trying to target the show me span when the checkboxes are checked and it's not working.

Here is the code and link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dalond/nonyg6sm/

```
$('.single').live('change', ':checkbox', function() {
var target = $(this).closest('.single').prev().find('.showMe');
if ($(this).find('input:checked').length == 0) {
    target.hide();
} else {
    target.show();
}
```

});

Comment: `<div>` elements don't have a `change` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it worked : http://jsfiddle.net/nonyg6sm/3/

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {

    var target = $(this).closest('.NoEd').prevAll(".Subs:first").find(".showMe");

    if (this.checked) {
        target.show();
    } else {
        target.hide();
    }
});
```

You can modify it to feet your need.

**UPDATE**

http://jsfiddle.net/nonyg6sm/4/

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {

    var target = $(this).closest('.NoEd').prevAll(".Subs:first").find(".showMe");

    if ($(this).closest('.NoEd').find("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length == 0) {
        target.hide();        
    } else {
        target.show();

    }
});
```

Comment: Your script seemed to function differently. I want the div to only hide when you uncheck box boxes and not one. Would you know how I can achieve that?

Comment: You mean the div will hide when Label1 and Print are unchecked ?

Comment: yeah when both are unchecked